# Ответ telegram-бота на определенные слова

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Хочу создать простого telegram-бота, установил библиотеку [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). 
Есть пример бота, который отвечает на команды (со слешем) и повторяет всё, что ему пишут (без слеша). Сам разобраться не смог:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.polling()
```

Как написать функцию, чтобы бот(**Б**) отвечал тебе на определенные слова и чтобы команда от юзера (**Ю**) отправлялась без слеша, например:

```
Ю: как тебя зовут?
Б: Коля
Ю: Холодно?
Б: Нет б., жарко!
```

А на остальные, "не забитые" слова, отвечал: "Я не понимаю, о чем ты..., может пояснишь?" Спасибо.

Comment: Предположим, вам удалось избавиться от проблемы со слешем. И что дальше? Будете создавать словарь вопросов-ответов? Первые две фразы для этого словаря вы уже написали. Сколько вариантов вопросов ещё осталось?
Даже если вы очень захотите, вы не сможете перечислить все возможные комбинации вопроса-ответа

Answer (score 5):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):

# Если пользователь отправил "привет, как тебя зовут?" отвечаем "робот я"
if message.text == "привет, как тебя зовут?":
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'робот я'

# Если пользователь отправил "и чо?" отвечаем "да ничо"
elif message.text == "и чо?":
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'да ничо'

#Если пользователь отправил слово/фразу, на которое(ую) нет ответа
else:
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Извините, я Вас не понимаю")
```

- python
- pyTelegramBotAPI

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, самый простой вариант вам уже предложили, но если вдруг интересно, либо хотите продвинуться чуть дальше, то посмотрите в сторону AIML, всё элементарно, с Python работает без проблем.